# Filter to prevent Samsung Galaxy Camera from accessing app from Play store

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-camera, android-permissions

Is there any way to apply filters in the Android manifest to prevent Samsung Galaxy Camera
or similar Android Camera devices from accessing a particular app from the play store.

using 
***uses - feature android:name=”android.hardware.telephony” android:required=”true”***
might work, but it would also filter tablets with no calling feature,

Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude individual devices through Google Play using 'excluded devices' section within the 'APK' tab in the developer console:

[image]

For more info, check out the 'Capabilities Targeting' section of [this page](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about/distribution.html).